# Using JOptionPane selection in an if else

Tags: java, arrays

I have a JOptionPane with a drop down selection with resolution pixels as selections and I need to add a multiplier to the selections to use in an if else command. Here is what I have and where Im at

```
  String [] resolution = new String [4];
  resolution [0] = "1280 x 720";
  resolution [1] = "1920 x 1080";
  resolution [2] = "2560 x 1440";
  resolution [3] = "3840 x 2160";

  Object selectedResolution = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose a Resolution", "Resolution", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, resolution, "1280 x 720");
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean: `"I need to add a multiplier to the selections"`? A multiplier for what?

Comment: Im doing this for a school project. I need to use the selected string variable in a formula and the multiplier is based off the choice the user  makes 1-4. when i try to use the selection in an if else statement the syntax error is cannot convert string to double. Im just stuck here and i dont know if i need to rewrite the JOptionPane code as something else....

Comment: Well what are you multiplying? Do you mean like: multiply 1280 by 720 (if that is what was selected)?